# Query works very slow

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables:

**Table tableA**

```
+----+---------+---------+---------------------+--------+
| id | columnA | columnB |     record_date     | result |
+----+---------+---------+---------------------+--------+
|  1 |   1111  |   1317  | 23.07.2018 02:11:01 |   538  |
|  2 |   0411  |   1317  | 23.07.2018 02:11:01 |     0  |
|  3 |   1111  |   1317  | 24.07.2018 13:08:17 |    13  |
|  4 |   0411  |   1317  | 24.07.2018 13:08:17 |   120  |
|  5 |   0506  |   1317  | 24.07.2018 13:08:17 |    17  |
|  6 |   0273  |   1317  | 24.07.2018 13:08:17 |  3256  |
| .. |     ..  |     ..  |          ..         |    ..  |
+----+---------+---------+---------------------+--------+
```

**Table tableB**

```
+----+---------+---------+---------------------+--------+------------+-------+
| id | columnA | columnB |     record_date     | result |  date_add  | delta |
+----+---------+---------+---------------------+--------+------------+-------+
|  1 |   1111  |   1317  | 23.07.2018 02:11:01 |   538  | 23.07.2018 |   0   |
|  2 |   0411  |   1317  | 23.07.2018 02:11:01 |     0  | 23.07.2018 |   0   |
| .. |     ..  |     ..  |          ..         |    ..  |     ..     |  ..   |
+----+---------+---------+---------------------+--------+------------+-------+
```

Both tables have indices on fields: columnA, columnB, record_date.

I'm wrote function that looks for missing rows in `tableB`, calculates delta and inserts missing rows into `tableB`, but with a large data set (over 10000 rows), the function works very slowly. How can I increase the performance of a function?

Here is my function:

```
declare
  delta numeric(38,0);
  lastresult numeric(38,0);
  row record;

begin
  for row in select A.*
    from tableA as A
    where not exists (select 1 
                      from tableB B
                      where B.id = A.id
                      order by A.record_date) loop
    select B.result into lastresult
    from tableB B
    group by B.result, B.columnA, B.columnB, B.record_date 
    having row.columnA = B.columnA 
        and row.columnB = B.columnB 
        and row.record_date > B.record_date
    order by B.record_date desc
    limit 1;
    if lastresult is null then 
        delta = 0;
    else
        delta = row.result - lastresult;
    end if;

    lastresult := null;

    insert into tableB select
        row.id,
        row.columnA,
        row.columnB,
        row.record_date,
        row.result,
        now(),
        delta; 

  end loop;
end;
```

After function operation `tableB` would be like:

```
+----+---------+---------+---------------------+--------+------------+-------+
| id | columnA | columnB |     record_date     | result |  date_add  | delta |
+----+---------+---------+---------------------+--------+------------+-------+
|  1 |   1111  |   1317  | 23.07.2018 02:11:01 |   538  | 23.07.2018 |   0   |
|  2 |   0411  |   1317  | 23.07.2018 02:11:01 |     0  | 23.07.2018 |   0   |
|  3 |   1111  |   1317  | 24.07.2018 13:08:17 |    13  | 24.07.2018 | -525  |
|  4 |   0411  |   1317  | 24.07.2018 13:08:17 |   120  | 24.07.2018 |  120  |
|  5 |   0506  |   1317  | 24.07.2018 13:08:17 |    17  | 24.07.2018 |   0   |
|  6 |   0273  |   1317  | 24.07.2018 13:08:17 |  3256  | 24.07.2018 |   0   |
| .. |     ..  |     ..  |         ..          |    ..  | 24.07.2018 |  ..   |
+----+---------+---------+---------------------+--------+------------+-------+
```

The main problem why I can't use `INSERT` … `SELECT` … `FROM` is that in `tableA` maybe several rows which must be added with the same values of columns columnA, columnB and minimum time difference of column record_date, something like this:

```
+----+---------+---------+---------------------+--------+
| id | columnA | columnB |     record_date     | result |
+----+---------+---------+---------------------+--------+
| .. |     ..  |     ..  |           ..        |    ..  |
|  9 |   3456  |   1317  | 24.07.2018 12:55:57 |   324  |
| 10 |   3456  |   1317  | 24.07.2018 13:08:17 |    13  |
+----+---------+---------+---------------------+--------+
```

and both of this rows must be added to `tableB` and delta must be calculated.

Comment: Given your sample data, what exactly should be inserted into `tableb`? Assuming id = 4 is missing in tableb what value should the delta column get then? And assuming there is another row missing with (id = 100, columna = 0411, columnb = 1317, result = 200), what should be the value for `delta` for **that** row? And why is that delta store in a separate table? It looks like you could remove tablea completely. I think you can replace the function (and thus the loop) with a single `insert ... select ... from` statement which would be a lot faster

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I updated question

Comment: I think calculating that delta in a single statement using `lag()` should be possible

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can you show how it should look like?